# Setting Up Codeen Proxy?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I am trying to get access to ESPN so that I can watch the Scripps National Spelling Bee next week, but my ISP does not pay off ESPN so that I can watch clips on their site. It says that universities have access and I am attending the U of U, but I can still only watch it if I am on campus, which is not preferable since it takes me an hour to travel up there and I am taking a break for the summer and just working. Anyhow without telling you my life story, I am trying to use a Codeen proxy (.edu) to trick ESPN into thinking I am at a university. I got so far as to getting the proxy list (address & IP) and going to "under the hood" -> "proxy settings" -> "LAN Settings" (using Chrome broswer). It didn't list what port to use so I used a portscanner and came to found 80 (http) and 22 (SSH) are the only open ports. I either get a 404 error or " has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete." Can anyone tell me/direct me to somewhere that explains more thoroughly and explicitly how I can get this set up? Or if someone already has ESPN access or knows a better way, I am totally up for alternate options. Thanks!

Comment: Was able to bypass the popup that yells at me because my I am not on their list of accepted list of ISP's. I think the proxy that I am using has a dynamic IP that is not necessarily coming from a .edu domain every time, thus once I gain access to the streaming app, it gets an error because I am no longer being accepted or something? Hmmm, ideas?